# optimize with non-linear constraint in python - division by sum of variables

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming

I have an optimization problem. all of my other constraints are linear but I have a constraint that is like this:

[image]

in this equation, s and r and k are constants that I have the values and a and s are unknown parameters.

actually, the objective function is:

[image]

and it has some other linear constraints.

I'm searching for a python package that can solve this problem and can make that constraint that I mentioned above as a parameter for the optimization problem.
I first searched for linear programming solutions but when I tried to make that constraint in pulp I got this error:

```
TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Try non-linear programming. You cannot use LP if one constraint is non-linear.

Comment: Are p values known or unknown?

Comment: You can introduce an auxiliary variable `t > 0` and replace the constraint by `C_i = t * a_i * p_i^(1-r)`.

Comment: @GZ0 they are known in an array that I have the values in it.

Comment: You might try to see whether it is possible to introduce auxiliary variables to make it an LP problem.

Comment: @GZ0 how can I introduce an auxiliary variable? the array of p is known but the array of a is unknown for me... so the value of sum in the dominator is not a constant.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin which python package can I use for non-linear programming??

Comment: Try pyOpt. Looks like it is what you need.

Comment: @niloofar latifian It depends on what the other constraints look like.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt):

```
from pyscipopt import Model
model = Model()
x = model.addVar("x")
y = model.addVar("y")
z = model.addVar("z")
model.setObjective(c)
model.addCons(x / (y*z) >= 0)
model.optimize()
```

You can formulate any polynomial expression in this way.